# Как в WordPress разделить выпадающие меню на колонки?

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap

Как с помощью WP-Bootstrap-Navwalker разделить выпадающие меню на колонки? как вот здесь:[image: меню с 3 колонками]

У меня получается только вот так: [image: мое меню]

```html
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'depth'    => 2, // 1 = with dropdowns, 0 = no dropdowns.
 'container'   => 'div',
 'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
 'container_id'  => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
 'menu_class'  => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
    'fallback_cb'  => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'   => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
) );
?>

</nav>
```

```html
<!-- Navigation-->
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="mainNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills ">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Главная</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="page/company.html">О компании</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="servicesjs">Услуги</a>
        <div class="container-fluid dropdown-menu submenu1 multi-column columns-3 ">
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4><a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/repairs.html">Ремонт гидрооборудования</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/repairs_hydrocylindrs.html">Ремонт гидроцилиндров</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/hydromotors.html">Ремонт героторных гидромоторов</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/piston-pumps.html">Ремонт аксиально-поршневых насосов, моторов</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/hydraulic-distributor.html">Ремонт гидрораспределителей</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/hydro_rotators.html">Ремонт гидровращателей</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/dosing_pumps.html">Ремонт насосов-дозаторов</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/hydraulic-molot.html">Ремонт гидромолотов</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4><a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/diagnostics.html">Диагностика гидросистем</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/diagnostics2.html">Диагностика гидросистем с выездом специалиста</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/test_stend.html">Испытание гидравлических агрегатов на специализированном стенде</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4><a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/diagnostics.html">Другие работы</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/stend.html">Регулировка клапанной аппаратуры</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/pneumatic.html">Заправка азотом пневмогидроаккумуляторов</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/turning_works.html">Токарные работы</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="stockjs">Продажа</a>
        <div class="container-fluid dropdown-menu submenu2 multi-column columns-3 ">
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4><a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/sale.html">Штока и трубы</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/stocks_trumpets.html">Продажа труб для гидроцилиндров</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/rod.html">Продажа штоков для гидроцилиндров</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4> <a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/sale.html">Изготовление гидрооборудования</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/making_cylinders.html">Изготовление гидроцилидров</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/rvd.html">Изготовление РВД</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li>
                  <h4> <a class="dropdown-caption" href="page/sale.html">Комплектующие для гидравлики</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page/new_hydro.html">Продажа комплектующих для гидравлики</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="page/contact.html">Контакты</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- End navigation-->
```

Comment: Делайте три подменю, а дальше вёрсткой.

Comment: А пример можно?

Comment: Пример готового сайта - могу http://vc.mint-studio.org/ я делал выпадающее меню. Смотрите верстку, копируйте. Дать тут всю верстку - проблематично. У вас в вопросе нет меню, да и делать такую объемную работу в качетсве ответа тут не принято

Comment: добавил меню. вопрос мой как делить в WP выпадающие меню на колонки с заголовками? или где можно увидеть пример нарезки меню, почитать про это

Comment: я же вам дал пример. Смотрите html и css код в браузере.